# How to display PHP code as a string inside other PHP code

Tags: php, paypal

I need to paste this code at admin panel and then display Paypal Button on website.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6UKjJ8hU6ML5f">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php print($_SESSION['mid'].'-'.$_SESSION['mps']);?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Then, need to display this code on website using following code.

```
print $rs->fields("ppbutton");
```

Now, problem is that due to PHP code inside Paypal form, whenever I try to print above value (paypal button) on website, it's giving error because of PHP code inside another PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

I also think, print htmlentities($rs->fields("ppbutton"));

is the best option for you.

You can get the most recent updates about the function from this site.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: It's display entire paypal button code as a string, not like Button so buyer can click.

Comment: So, you want that code to appear inside the button, then wrap inside, the button tag.

Comment: I want to display paypal button code properly with 2 php variables as hidden elements on page once I print paypal code on page. Please ask if you need more info. I am trying for long.

Answer (score 0):

```
print htmlentities($rs->fields("ppbutton"));
```

Comment: It's display entire paypal button code as a string, not like Button so buyer can click.